# Why the excel file of xml sized large ,is it there any way to reduce it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, openoffice-calc

i am trying to open 9 MB excel file in open office calc,it takes lot time ,so i opened it with archive manager to find whats wrong with the excel file

[image]

While opening it with archive manager i could see a xml file sized 105 MB ,which buzzed me why the file size was large for the xml file?is it safe to delete and load it in open calc,will my excel spreadsheet will get loaded faster if i delete the xml?
[image]

Why the size gets varied ,is it there any way to optimize and open it faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An xlsx file is a zip compressed format, which is why it is 9MB while the content is 105MB.  When you look at the contents in the archive manager, you are seeing the XML files that comprise the two sheets of your spreadsheet.

If you delete sheet1.xml then it will load faster, but you will lose everything in sheet one.

If you don't need sheet one, then you can just delete it in Excel or OpenOffice Calc or any other application that can edit xlsx files.

Comment: Technically, you can also delete it, in `open office calc`.

Comment: @Ramhound True enough (and you are welcome to edit answers)